# Is there an incompatibility between `eulervm` and `fourier` packages?

Tags: fonts, fourier

In the following minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier,eulervm}
\begin{document}
$1 < 2$
\end{document}
```

the output is missing the `<` symbol.

On the other hand, if I load the two font packages in the opposite order

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm,fourier}
\begin{document}
$1 < 2$
\end{document}
```

the output is as it should.  **Why?**

I could not find this documented anywhere.

**Added**

A less minimal example would also show that whereas in the latter case the `<` does appear, the math fonts being used are not the Euler fonts.  Hence I do think that the two are incompatible.  I'm starting to think that perhaps incompatibility between different font packages is the norm and not the exception?

Comment: My log says: `Missing character: There is no \202 in font zeusm10!`, but I have no idea what is wrong here.

Comment: I didn't find anything strange in my log file, though.  This is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both packages mess around with the maths font loading, so you'd generally expect problems to arise loading them together. What are the combinations of fonts you're trying to use?

Comment: "What are the combinations of fonts you're trying to use?"  I wasn't trying to control this, other than with the default.  In other words, there was no further font commands than those in the minimal document above.  In case anyone else is interested, I've since found a compatible (and appealing) font with the Euler maths font: TeXGyre Pagella.

Comment: I think the fourier font package uses utopia as its text font.